# LINQ - How to exclude conditions of CONTAINS predicate when input parameter is null?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm facing an issue when trying to LINQ an array of items.
Based on my input argument, I want to exclude from the predicate criteria if an input value is null:

```
public record Card(Guid Id, List<CardAttribute> Attributes);
public record CardAttribute(Guid CardId, string Key, string Value, string Searchable);

query.Where(card => {
  return card.Attributes.Any(attribute => {
    // Here is the deal!

    // the attribute should be searchable, easy to spot.
    attribute.Searchable = true;

    // In case the input key is null, I want to add a contains clause to this predicate.
    if (input.Key != null)
      attribute.Key.Contains(input.Key);

    // The same applies for value.
    if (input.Value != null)
      attribute.Value.Contains(input.Value);
  });
});
```

How can I turn this to a proper LINQ operation, returning a `boolean` value out of the condition but still ignoring a given condition whenever an input parameter is null?

Thank y'all!

Comment: `attribute.Searchable = true;` that's an assignment. I guess it should have been `attribute.Searchable == true;` as one of the conditions?

Comment: @Fildor yes! Should be a comparison. Nevertheless, I can't get to an interesting option when it goes for the null comparison.

Comment: LINQ operations like `Where` return a *new* IQueryable to which you can apply more `Where` or other operations. You can construct a query dynamically this way, eg `if (condition) query=query.Where(....);`. Chaining multiple `.Where` is equivalent to ANDing the conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> // In case the input key is null, I want to add a contains clause to this predicate.

is unclear to me. I would have thought you wanted quite the opposite:

```
query.Where(card => card.Attributes.Any(attribute => 
    attribute.Searchable && // == true is not needed
    ( input.Key is null || attribute.Key.Contains(input.Key)) &&
    ( input.Value is null || attribute.Value.Contains(input.Value))
));
```

Explanation: In a `a || b` expression, `b` is only evaluated, if `a` is `false`. So, in `input.Key is null || attribute.Key.Contains(input.Key)` if `input.Key` is null, the right hand side won't be evaluated and the expression evaluates to `true`.

Which means in other words: Either input.Key is null or attribute.Key must contain it.

Same goes for Value. And since all of the three conditions must be satisfied, they are combined with `&&`.

When dealing with Linq2SQL, you'll have to keep in mind how this is going to be translated to SQL, though. In that case above solution probably will result in poorly performing queries.

I am not able to test this extensively, but an improved version considering SQL Execution Plans should be something along these lines:

```
query.Where(card => 
    {
       var searchable = card.Attributes.Where(attr => attr.Searchable);
       if (input.Key is not null) 
          searchable = searchable.Where(attr => attr.Key.Contains(input.Key);
       if (input.Value is not null)
          searchable = searchable.Where(attr => attr.Value.Contains(input.Value);
       return searchable.Any();   
    });
```

The idea behind this is that the query can be translated into an SQL that only contains the neccessary filters etc. to enable the database to further optimize execution.

For example: we don't need the db to figure out that one of the parameters we gave is null, we can instead just omit that whole clause and it will never even be considered by the db.

Comment: Why a catch-all query insted of `if (input.Key !=null ) query=query.Where(att=>att.Key.Contains(input.Key));` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No particular reason. To me, that's just two equally readable versions. But I'll consider it in the answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos On second glance: Mind that the conditionals are on the inner `card.Attributes.Any` statement ... but I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: In SQL there's a huge difference. Catch-all queries result in bad execution plans

Comment: **If** that's the case (Linq2SQL), then that has to be taken into account, yes. And on a query, that's quite likely.

Comment: That would only matter if Linq2SQL was smart enough to optimize the catch-all and *modified* the expression to eliminate the dead clauses. If the catch-all reaches the database, the generated execution plan will cause problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added an attempt, but cannot really test/verify atm. Does that look reasonable to you?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BTW: Thank you for suggesting improvement instead of dv.

Comment: Thanks, @Fildor, your answer helped out with the enigma of the query!